# Prefix article keyword with date(Y-m-d)

Tags: javascript

In the CMS I am building, record names have to be unique (they are URL keywords). In order to achieve this with blog posts, I am attempting to prefix blog post titles with date("Y-m-d") in PHP.

I have a "title" input text field, in which the title is entered, a "keyword" text field which automatically "slugs" the title in order to turn it into a URL keyword.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to prefix the slugged title with the date.

Here's the code:

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" />

<input name="keyword" type="text" id="slug" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#title").slug();
}); 
</script>
```

This part works. The title successfully turns into a keyword with dashes for spaces, eliminating special characters, etc.

I tried including the date by adding a hidden field with the date as the value and accessing its value with the getElementById function. I attempted to rework the javascript to concatenate the slugged title with the date:

```
<input type = "hidden" id = "postdate" value = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>-" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var getDate = document.getElementById('postdate');
  var doSlug = $("#title").val();
  var slugString = getDate + doSlug;
   $("slugString").slug();
}); 
</script>
```

But I'm obviously not working properly with the javascript.

The output I'm after would be: "2013-10-09-title-of-this-blog-post"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Here is the 'slug' function js in case it is helpful to look at: [slug.js](http://mjanglican.org/js/jquery.slug.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxkVJ/)</kbd>

I suggest you to do a little *tweak* to the plugin to be able to do what you want.
As you can see in the feedle above i add two new configuration parameters

```
prepend: null, // String to be prepended the sluged string
append: null // String to be appended the sluged string
```

and on the `makeSlug` function i just add this two conditionals

```
if(typeof settings.append === 'string')
    slug = slug + '-' + settings.append;
if(typeof settings.prepend === 'string')
    slug = settings.prepend + '-' + slug;
```

Now you can prepend or append a string to the slugfy version of your string

```
$("#title").slug({
    prepend: '2010-10-13',
    append: 'YAYY'
});
```

---

If you decide to use this approach, here is how to use with your html

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#title").slug({ 
       prepend: $('#postdate').val() 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var getDate = $('#postdate').val(); // get the value of the postdate id, not the element.
  var doSlug = $("#title").val();
  var slugString = getDate + "-" + doSlug;
  $('#title').val(slugString);
  $('#title').slug(); // if needed.
});
```

The jQuery slug() function is changing the input value to be "slugged". You can't set it to "slugString", because that's a variable, not a dom element. If necessary, you can "reslug" the input value after setting it with val().

Edited to fix the getDate variable issue that @Oswaldo Acauan picked up

Comment: Thanks for the response! This script seems to add the date to the title, which then adds it to the keyword. I'm hoping to add the date to the keyword only, and to leave the title undated.

I'm guessing this happens at $('#title').val(slugString); ?